Counting pairs $(x,y)$ of positive integers such that $x\leq y$, $GCD(x,y)=5!$, and $LCM(x,y) =50!$. What's wrong with my reasoning?
The exercice states:

How many pairs $(x,y)$ of positive integers such as $x\leq y$ satisfy $GCD(x,y) =5!$ and $LCM(x,y) =50!\;$?

and here's my reasoning that the teacher told me was wrong without giving a clue:
Let's start by decomposing $50!$ into prime factors. We use Legendre's formula to calculate the p-adic valuation of a factorial.
$$
\nu_p(n!)= \sum_{k \geq 1} \left\lfloor \frac{n}{p^k} \right\rfloor
$$
So, we decompose $50!$:
\begin{aligned}
\nu_2(50) &= \sum_{1 \leq k \leq 5} \left\lfloor \frac{50}{2^k} \right\rfloor = 25 + 12 + 6 + 3 + 1 = 47 \\
\nu_3(50) &= \sum_{1 \leq k \leq 3} \left\lfloor \frac{50}{3^k} \right\rfloor = 16 + 5 + 1 = 22 \\
\nu_5(50) &= \sum_{1 \leq k \leq 2} \left\lfloor \frac{50}{5^k} \right\rfloor = 10 + 2 = 12 \\
\nu_7(50) &= \sum_{1 \leq k \leq 2} \left\lfloor \frac{50}{7^k} \right\rfloor = 7 + 1 = 8 \\
\nu_{11}(50) &= \left\lfloor \frac{50}{11} \right\rfloor = 4 \\
\nu_{13}(50) &= \left\lfloor \frac{50}{13} \right\rfloor = 3 \\
\nu_{17}(50) &= \left\lfloor \frac{50}{17} \right\rfloor = 2 \\
\nu_{19}(50) &= \left\lfloor \frac{50}{19} \right\rfloor = 2 \\
\nu_{23}(50) &= \left\lfloor \frac{50}{23} \right\rfloor = 2
\end{aligned}
For prime numbers $p$ such that $25 < p \leq 50$, we obviously have $\nu_p(50) = 1$:
$$50! = 2^{47} \cdot 3^{22} \cdot 5^{12} \cdot 7^8 \cdot 11^4 \cdot 13^3 \cdot 17^2 \cdot 19^2 \cdot 23^2 \cdot 29 \cdot 31 \cdot 37 \cdot 41 \cdot 43 \cdot 47$$
SO :
$$xy = 50! \cdot 5! = 2^{50} \cdot 3^{23} \cdot 5^{13} \cdot 7^8 \cdot 11^4 \cdot 13^3 \cdot 17^2 \cdot 19^2 \cdot 23^2 \cdot 29 \cdot 31 \cdot 37 \cdot 41 \cdot 43 \cdot 47$$
We need pairs $(x,y)$ such that:
$$ x = 5! \cdot k$$
$$ y = 5! \cdot l $$
$$(k,l) = 1$$
$$k \cdot l = \frac{50!}{5!} = 2^{44} \cdot 3^{21} \cdot 5^{11} \cdot 7^8 \cdot 11^4 \cdot 13 ^3 \cdot 17^2 \cdot 19^2 \cdot 23^2 \cdot 29 \cdot 31 \cdot 37 \cdot 41 \cdot 43 \cdot 47 $$
Each distinct prime factor of $k \cdot l $ can be assigned to either $k$ or $ l $ in $2$ ways, while maintaining $ \operatorname{gcd}(k, l) = 1$.
Since there are 15 distinct primes in the factorization of $k \cdot l $:
The number of possible pairs $(k, l) = 2^{15} $
However, we need to count pairs such as $ x \leq y $, which means:
$$x \leq y \Rightarrow 5! \cdot k \leq 5! \cdot l \Rightarrow k \leq l $$
Thus, we consider only half of the possible pairs:
$$ \frac{2^{15}}{2} = 2^{14} $$
So, the number of such pairs is:
$$2^{14} = 16384$$
Therefore, the correct number of pairs $(x, y)$ such that $ x \leq y $, $\operatorname{pgcd}(x, y)$ and $\operatorname{ppcm}(x, y) = 50 ! $ is:
$$ \boxed{16384} $$

How do you know that this is wrong?

What did the teacher say was the correct answer? This looks fine to me. You don't even need the specific exponents.

Your calculations of $\nu_p(50\color{red}!)$ are useless (same comment as @lulu below). That said, does your teacher want to count pairs ${x,y}$ or ordered pairs $(x,y)$?

Note:  there is no need to deal with the factorization of $50!$   We just need the count, $15$, of primes $<50$.

@Anne Bauval ordered pairs such that x<=y
